# Beamer with ragged2e and babel results in "command \selectfont has changed" warning

Tags: beamer, babel, ragged2e

I am preparing a presentation in beamer and trying to get rid of warnings – but there is one that I cannot remove. In the MWE below there's empty beamer document with babel in Polish and ragged2e packages loaded. The resulting log gives `Command \selectfont has changed`. It is not an error but just a warning, nevertheless I guess that it may mean that this conjunction is incompatible in some way. Changing babel from `polish` to e.g. `english` causes the warning to disappear.

I didn't manage to find a reason for this behavior in other answers, but maybe someone here would determine its cause. I'm using MiKTeX 64-bit + TeXstudio on Win 8.1.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[polish]{babel}

\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`babel-polish` changes `\selectfont` due to the differences in the encoding needed for Polish. It is just telling you this has been done. This is part of what you pay `babel` to do.

Here's the relevant bit from the language file `babel` loads:

```
\ifx\selectfont\@undefined
  \ifx\prm\@undefined \addto\rm{\textpl}\else \addto\prm{\textpl}\fi
  \ifx\pit\@undefined \addto\it{\textpl}\else \addto\pit{\textpl}\fi
  \ifx\pbf\@undefined \addto\bf{\textpl}\else \addto\pbf{\textpl}\fi
  \ifx\psl\@undefined \addto\sl{\textpl}\else \addto\psl{\textpl}\fi
  \ifx\psf\@undefined                   \else \addto\psf{\textpl}\fi
  \ifx\psc\@undefined                   \else \addto\psc{\textpl}\fi
  \ifx\ptt\@undefined \addto\tt{\telepl}\else \addto\ptt{\telepl}\fi
\else
  \expandafter\addto\csname selectfont \endcsname{%
    \csname\f@encoding @pl\endcsname}
\fi
\expandafter\let\csname T1@pl\endcsname\textpl
\expandafter\def\csname OT1@pl\endcsname{%
  \long\edef\curr@family{\f@family}%
  \ifx\curr@family\ttdefault
    \telepl
  \else
    \textpl
  \fi}
```